# Joining multiple rows based on a grouping factor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a SQL query that will left join multiple rows together based on a grouping factor. Hopefully someone can help.

Example Data:

```
Code

001A

001B

001C

002A

002B

002C

002D

002E
```

I would want a query that does `Where Code LIKE '001%'` Then Left Join all the rows.
Resulting in:

```
Code1   Code2   Code3

001A    001B    001C
```

In the data there would be variances in the number of codes that it would pick up for example on a `Where Code Like '002%'`:

```
Code1   Code2   Code3   Code4   Code5

002A    002B    002C    002D    002E
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `pivot` and some dynamic query:

```
declare @cols varchar(max), @query varchar(max)

set @cols = stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename(code)
                   from t
                   where code like '002%'
                   for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)') 
                  ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'select * from (select code from t)t
              pivot (max(code) for code in (' + @cols + ')) p'
exec(@query)
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4da68/10

Comment: That looks like exactly what was after, however how do I modify this so that it is only looking at the "code" column and not picking up any other columns that may be on the table? Thanks.